# acquiring nested rwlocks in a thread-safe way?

Tags: rust, mutex, rwlock

I am managing some per-customer data in a thread-safe way as follows:

`customer_id_to_data: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>`

It's very important that I not acquire the write lock on the HashMap unless it's absolutely necessary, which is only when I'm creating a new `CustomerId` or deleting one.

The function that is supposed to be adding or updating a single new CustomerData needs to look like this:

```
fn load_customer_data_impl(
    customer_id_to_data: &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>,
    customer_id: &CustomerId,
    new_data: CustomerData,
) -> () {
    if !{
        let read_guard = Self::get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id_to_data);
        if !read_guard.contains_key(customer_id) {
            false
        } else {
            let mut data_write_guard = read_guard
                .get(customer_id)
                .unwrap()  // just checked, still holding rlock
                .write()
                .unwrap_or_else(|| sys::process::exit(1));
            *data_write_guard = new_index;
            true
        }
    } {
        let mut write_guard = Self::get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard(customer_id_to_data);
        write_guard.insert(*customer_id, Arc::new(RwLock::new(new_data)));
        }
    }
```

This formulation satisfies the necessary conditions that

- I do not let go of the read guard between checking contains_key and `.get().unwrap()`
- The read guard falls out of scope before I access the write guard
- The object `new_data` can only be moved once, either in the `if` clause of the `if` body.

However, the compiler complains about this last point: it does not see that if I have moved `new_data` in the if clause, I will never reach the `if` body.

I can't figure out how to re-organize this method to prevent that from happening.

As an attempt, the following naive code does NOT work, because the read guard in the `if` clause is released before it is re-acquired in the `if` body which may give rise to a race condition:

```
if Self::get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id_to_data).contains_key(customer_id) {
    let read_guard = Self::get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id);
    let mut data_write_guard = read_guard
        .get(customer_id)
        .unwrap()  // just checked, still holding rlock
        .write()
        .unwrap_or_else(|| sys::process::exit(1));
    *data_write_guard = new_data;        
} else {
    let mut write_guard = Self::get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard(customer_id_to_data);
    write_guard.insert(*customer_id, Arc::new(RwLock::new(new_data)));
}
```

Another naive non-starter is like

```
if !get_read_lock().contains_key(...) {
    get_write_lock().insert(...);
} else {
    *get_read_lock().get_index_write_lock(...) = new_data;
}
```

which has the same failure mode of a race condition between checking the `if` clause and entering the `else` body.

I am aware of the [if-let-chains RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2497-if-let-chains.md) which would seem to be a way out, but don't see how to write a correct implementation without it.

Comment: Please provide a proper [MRE]. I might guess some of the missing things, but having a `Self::` inside of a normal function just simply makes no sense to me. Also, the return types of `Self::get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard` and `Self::get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard` seem to be quite relevant to the question. Also, if you claim that *"the compiler complains"*, then please provide the [MRE] that causes the compiler error, as well as the compiler error itself as printed by `cargo check`.

Comment: Also, in your first example, you claim that you use `new_data` in the `if` condition, but you don't. Further, the `new_index` variable spawns out of nowhere. Again, plese provide a [MRE] otherwise I don't think we can help you much.

Comment: Can I assume that [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d0f5356ffe58c3f8c5153ccc270f4b3) is your minimal reproducible example? If so, please [edit] your question to reflect that.

Comment: You're right, I wrote the question rather hastily at the end of the day. Thanks for your help and willingness to interpret the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that this is your minimal reproducible example:

```rust
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, RwLock, RwLockReadGuard, RwLockWriteGuard},
};

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone, Copy)]
struct CustomerId;
struct CustomerData;

fn get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(
    s: &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>,
) -> RwLockReadGuard<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>> {
    s.read().unwrap()
}

fn get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard(
    s: &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>,
) -> RwLockWriteGuard<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>> {
    s.write().unwrap()
}

fn load_customer_data_impl(
    customer_id_to_data: &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>,
    customer_id: &CustomerId,
    new_data: CustomerData,
) -> () {
    if !{
        let read_guard = get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id_to_data);
        if !read_guard.contains_key(customer_id) {
            false
        } else {
            let mut data_write_guard = read_guard
                .get(customer_id)
                .unwrap() // just checked, still holding rlock
                .write()
                .unwrap_or_else(|_| std::process::exit(1));
            *data_write_guard = new_data;
            true
        }
    } {
        let mut write_guard = get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard(customer_id_to_data);
        write_guard.insert(*customer_id, Arc::new(RwLock::new(new_data)));
    }
}
```

The solution is quite simple. The reason why the compiler gets confused is that it doesn't understand that `false`/`true` in your `if` condition reflect different lifetimes of `new_data`. Lifetimes are a compile time thing, and the content of a boolean variable is a runtime information.

The point where the compiler knows that `new_data` is available is where you generate the `false` value - simply put your code there :)

The only pitfall is that the `read_guard` also still exists there, so aquiring a `write_guard` there would cause a deadlock. But luckily the `drop()` function exists to fix that:

```rust
fn load_customer_data_impl(
    customer_id_to_data: &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>,
    customer_id: &CustomerId,
    new_data: CustomerData,
) -> () {
    let read_guard = get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id_to_data);
    if !read_guard.contains_key(customer_id) {
        drop(read_guard);
        let mut write_guard = get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard(customer_id_to_data);
        write_guard.insert(*customer_id, Arc::new(RwLock::new(new_data)));
    } else {
        let mut data_write_guard = read_guard
            .get(customer_id)
            .unwrap() // just checked, still holding rlock
            .write()
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| std::process::exit(1));
        *data_write_guard = new_data;
    }
}
```

You can further improve your code by avoiding the `.contains_key` function, which causes an unnecessary table lookup. Simply use `.get` directly:

```rust
fn load_customer_data_impl(
    customer_id_to_data: &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<CustomerId, Arc<RwLock<CustomerData>>>>>,
    customer_id: &CustomerId,
    new_data: CustomerData,
) -> () {
    let read_guard = get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id_to_data);
    if let Some(existing_data) = read_guard.get(customer_id) {
        let mut data_write_guard = existing_data
            .write()
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| std::process::exit(1));
        *data_write_guard = new_data;
    } else {
        drop(read_guard);
        let mut write_guard = get_customer_id_to_data_write_guard(customer_id_to_data);
        write_guard.insert(*customer_id, Arc::new(RwLock::new(new_data)));
    }
}
```

As a last remark: `unwrap_or_else(|_| std::process::exit(1))` is kind of an antipattern. Even `panic!()` or `.unwrap()` still cause destructors of objects to run, which could close file handles or shutdown database connections. `exit()` prevents all those things, so use it with care.

Comment: > unwrap_or_else(|_| std::process::exit(1)) is kind of an antipattern

yes, this was just a placeholder for actual error handling, that's obviously not what I have running in production.  I should have just stuck with `.unwrap()` for this example.

Comment: > But luckily the drop() function exists to fix that:

For some reason, I was under the impression that calling `drop()` explicitly was discouraged if not incorrect. Will try this shortly.

Comment: Your last suggestion is the best, and is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: Seems that in this final formulation, the `drop()` in the `else` clause should be unnecessary if one doesn't declare "read_guard" as a variable: "if let Some(existing_data) = get_customer_id_to_data_read_guard(customer_id_to_data).get(customer_id)" a

Comment: Yes, you are probably right that this would make the `drop()` unnecessary. And no, I'm not sure where you got the idea from that an explicit `drop()` is discouraged - it's a very normal pattern. It might be discouraged in other languages, but in Rust, due to lifetimes, you cannot use `drop()` incorrectly. The implementation of `drop()` is simply an empty function that gets its parameter passed as an owned value. There's no magic in it, it's the same as having a variable get out of scope. The borrow checker will prevent use-after-free scenarios or other kinds of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Fyi, here is the implementation of `drop()`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/mem/mod.rs.html#987 As mentioned, it doesn't do anything. It simply signals to the borrow checker that this is the point where the variable should be destroyed, instead of at the end of the scope.

Comment: Lovely, that makes sense. Not sure where I got that impression.